# Find questions with tag that are inactive six month ago

Tags: support, search

Is there a query which can return questions that are *inactive in six month ago* having a specific tag?

## Example:

#### Android Badge

Let's say I want the questions or posts which are inactive six month ago but the question or post have Android tag in it.

### Note:

**Read the question carefully.**

This question is not a *possible duplicate* of the following questions.

1. [How did I get the Excavator badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102412/how-did-i-get-the-excavator-badge)
2. [How to find inactive posts on Stack Overflow for archaeologist badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149602/how-to-find-inactive-posts-on-stack-overflow-for-archaeologist-badge)

To clarify:

The **short and simple explanation of my question** is to find the post by tag that are inactive six month ago.

Comment: What do you mean by "Specific question"? Are you looking for a particular question that is tagged Android and was last active 6 months ago?

Comment: @Tunaki Yes I want only `Android` tag question.

Comment: This needs to be untangled (and corresponding fixes to the grammar). Tags that *were* inactive some time ago, but are active now?? Or the youngest (last) question (in a particular tag) is older than six months? Or questions that haven't seen any activity (e.g. updates) in the last six months? Or questions that saw activity about six months ago (not before and not since)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, you can use a [custom search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) with `[android] lastactive:..6m is:q`.

- `[android]` will search questions having the Android tag.
- `lastactive:..6m` will search for posts last active 6 months ago or less.
- `is:q` will only return questions.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[android]+lastactive%3A..6m+is%3Aq

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is a change in the URL. For example, if you want go back to six month ago with `angular` tagged questions, you  can change the URL as below:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular?tab=active&page=845&pagesize=50
```

And change `page=854` frequently to reach your date.